# dns NXDOMAIN error with external view

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, linux-networking, bind, dig

we are trying to configure a bind9 server. We have two different views, one for the internal zone (dmz) and another for external users who want to access to the dmz web.

The problem is that we may be lacking any configuration option because the server is unable to resolv anything related with the external view.
In this link you will see the error image:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqB9E.png)

Our configuration is the following:

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders {
        10.45.1.2;
        10.40.1.2;
        10.40.1.108;
    };

    auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
view "Lab1A.int"{
    recursion yes;
    match-clients{172.16.0.0/24;198.18.10.0/28;localhost;};
    zone "lab10.int" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.grup1A.int";
    };

    zone "0.16.172.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.172";
        notify no;
    };

    zone "10.dmz" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.grup1A.dmz";
    };

    zone "10.18.198.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.198";
        notify no;
    };
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
};

view "Lab1A.ext"{
    match-clients{any;};
    recursion no;
    zone "grup10.gsx" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.grup1A.ext";
        allow-transfer{ localhost; };
    };

    zone "10.in-addr-arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.ext.rev";
        notify no;
    };
};
```

The files of the external zone are the following:

forward file, db.grup1A.ext

```
; file "db.grup1A.ext";
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns.grup10.gsx.   root.grup10.gsx.   (
    1   ; Serial
    604800  ; Refresh
    86400   ; Retry
    2419200 ; Expire
    604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns
ns  IN  A   10.21.1.17

www IN  A   10.21.1.17
```

reverse file, db.ext.rev

```
; file "db.ext.rev";
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.grup10.gsx.   root.grup10.gsx.     (
    1       ; Serial
    604800       ; Refresh
    86400       ; Retry
    2419200       ; Expire
    604800 )     ; Negative Cache TTL
    ;
@       IN      NS      ns.grup10.gsx.

17.1.21       IN      PTR     ns.grup10.gsx.

17.1.21 IN  PTR correu.grup10.gsx.
17.1.21 IN  PTR www.grup10.gsx.
```

/etc/default/bind9

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=no

# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

The ip of the server is 10.21.1.17 and it corresponds to the domain www.grup10.gsx

After trying the following command, there were no errors detacted.

```
named-checkzone grup10.gsx db.grup1A.ext
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `gsx` is not a valid top level domain (yet).

Comment: Nor `dmz` in fact.

Comment: You should more clearly explain, as text and not as an image, what you exactly tried, what errors you got and what results you expected instead. You can also use `named-checkconf`, look at your logfiles, and use external tools such as DNSViz and Zonemaster if your nameservers are reachable publicly.